# Built-in FxCop rule for avoiding unnecessary Boxing and Unboxing

Tags: c#, .net, fxcop

Is there a built-in FxCop rule that analyses for unnecessary Boxing/UnBoxing?

The following example shows a method, WeaklyTyped, which violates the rule and a method, StronglyTyped, which satisfies the rule.

```
using System;

namespace PerformanceLibrary
{
    public interface IWork
    {
       object DoWork();
    } 

    public class Work : IWork
    {
       object IWork.DoWork()
       {
           return 3;
       }

       public int DoWork()
       {
           return 3;
       }
    }

    public class NeedsWork
    {
        public void WeaklyTyped()
        {
            IWork iwork = new Work();
            // The following call violates the rule.
            int x = (int)iwork.DoWork();
        }

        public void StronglyTyped()
        {
            Work work = new Work();
            int x = work.DoWork();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a sample what you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'unecessary' here, could you expand?

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a rule for that but that is no longer in the current build of FxCop.

You can use the tool [BoxCop](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290247/BoxCop-Static-Assembly-Analyzer-tool) but that does not integrate nicely into the build process.